# Post text/message on friend's wall using FBShareDialogParams on ios 7 - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I can share link, with name, caption and description on Facebook friend's wall by using FBShareDialogParams, But I can't share text message with this link, or even only text without link.

For this i use below code:

```
FBShareDialogParams *sharedParams = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];

sharedParams.friends = fpc.selection;
NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_contentDataToShare];
sharedParams.description = @"See this link ..";
sharedParams.link = candidateURL;

if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:sharedParams]) {
   [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:sharedParams clientState:nil
                                handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                    if(error)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",error);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Posted AL7");
                                    }
                                }];

}
```

I'm working on IOS 7. and Facebook SDK 3.13.1.
I can post link successfully, but i need to post text message too, how can i do that ?
Event text only, or with link.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefilling the message is against Facebook Platform policies, which is why the SDK does not allow you to do it. The message MUST be user provided.

Comment: Thank you, true, I didn't find any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For more info, if any one need it..

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> From section IV.2 : "You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP."